# operator overloading c++ (x==y==z)

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I have encountered a strange problem, that I don't know how to solve in overloading.
Im trying too overload operator == .
The easy example would be:

```
class bla{
public:
int a;
void bla(int a):a(a){}//costructor
bool operator==(const bla& ob)
     return (a==ob.a);//chk if equal
};
void main(){
bla A,B;  
if (A==B)
   flag=1;//just an example...
```

this is easy and works great, i'm trying to handle the case of:

```
   if (A==B==C==D)
```

so i need to return type object and now type bool.
i have tried to add another function :

```
bla &bla:: operator==(const bool answer){//as a member function
if (answer)
    return *this;
```

but it doesn't seem to help. have any suggestions?
thx Stas

Comment: If you really must have this feature (and I call that into question), then you could make the operator return a proxy type that is both usable in a boolean context and in further comparisons.

Comment: Why?  How would it benefit you to change the expected syntax rules of C++?

Comment: Funny, `class bla` does not have field `x`!!!

Comment: I have to use it, that is an assignment. ill try to look for this proxy type u suggested thx.

Comment: Thx for the comment Barak, it doesn't matter its just an example, but i have edit it to make more sense.

Comment: Hi, @StavSer.  If this really is an assignment and you are being asked to support `A==B==C==D` syntax, that strongly implies that there's some critical detail about this assignment that you haven't shared.  Or the person who assigned this is out of their mind.

Comment: Hi this assignment was given to teach operator overloading, i can assure u there is no real need to write this kind of code.
But i have to make it work, as i was asked.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (A == B && B == C && C == D)`? Does the assignment literally demand you write `A==B==C==D` or are you just asked to check whether all four are equal?

Comment: @StavSer Probably possible but WAY harder than what should be taught in class... I'd say it includes about 2-3 overloaded operator== functions and maybe a static Boolean variable of the class but not so sure.
Maybe I'd try to implement it whenever.

Comment: Note that you are changing (or trying to change) the existing syntax of C++. If you do int a, b, c, and do `if (a == b == c)`, it will compare `a == b`, and then compare `c` with the result of that, which, 99.9% of the time, isn't what you want. So someone seeing the above code will certainly be very confused, unless it's made very clear everywhere that this is way it is used...

Comment: I was ask to implement that only at this way.
I can assure you it is doable.
kerrek, thx for the proxy suggestion but i'm not allowed to use it.

Comment: Mats, I wrote that the subject is operator overload so it would be relevant to who ever knows it.
The this is, if i don't compare objects the == operator would work the same.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't asked to provide the assignment operator? `A = B = C = D;` makes sense, `A==B==C==D` does not.

Comment: Hello Captain Giraffe,
I can assure u that i don't need to do A=B=C=D.
Its allot easier to implement what u suggested, this exercise isn't about smart implementation of code.

Comment: [use python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible idea and you should never do it.

Here is how you do it.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U>
struct decay_equiv
  : std::is_same<
    typename std::decay<T>::type,
    typename std::decay<U>::type
  >::type {};

template<typename T>
struct comparator {
  bool res;
  T passalong;
  explicit operator bool() { return res; }
  typename std::enable_if<
    !decay_equiv<T, comparator<T> >::value,
    comparator<T>
  >::type operator==(T const& rhs);
  comparator<T> operator==(comparator<T> const& rhs);
};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
  !decay_equiv<T, comparator<T>>::value,
  comparator<T>
>::type comparator<T>::operator==(T const& rhs) {
  if (!res) {
    return {res, rhs};
  }
  return {(passalong == rhs).res, rhs};
}

template<typename T>
comparator<T> comparator<T>::operator==(comparator<T> const& rhs) {
  if (!res || !rhs.res) {
    return {res, rhs};
  }
  return {(passalong == rhs.passalong).res, rhs.passalong};
}

struct bla {
  int a;
  comparator<bla> operator==(bla const& rhs);
  comparator<bla> operator==(comparator<bla> const& rhs);
};

comparator<bla> bla::operator==(bla const& rhs) {
  return {a == rhs.a, rhs};
}

comparator<bla> bla::operator==(comparator<bla> const& rhs) {
  if (!rhs.res) {
    return rhs;
  }
  return {a == rhs.passalong.a, rhs.passalong};
}

int main() {
  bla a = {0},b = {0},d = {0};
  if (a==b==d)
    return 0;
  return -1;
}
```

This code assumes C++11, but can be written in C++98 with only very minor changes.

Comment: Thx allot i don't know how to use template, but i'll look it up.

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to find a different approach and it seems to work great. 
thx to u all for your help and suggestions.

```
class bla{
public:
int a;
bool f;
void bla(int a):a(a){f = true;}//costructor
operator bool(){return f};
bla& operator==(const bla &ob){//chk if equal
    if (f)
       f=(a==ob.a);
     return *this;
}
};
void main(){
bla A(4),B(4),C(4),D(4);  
if (A==B==C==D)
   flag=1;//just an example...
```

Comment: You may wish to make `f` a private member in that case.  Also your code breaks if you make two comparisons in a row, the first one failing.

Comment: An example: `bla A(1), B(2), C(1); if (A==B==C) int flag = 1; B.a=1; if (A==B==C) int flag=1;` will erroneously fail the second comparison.